# perform non locking select when updating another table

Tags: mariadb, locking, mariadb-10.2

We need to perform the following (periodic) query in mariadb:

```
update A set status='INACTIVE' where status='ACTIVE' and a.b_id in
(select id from B where ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE);
```

Unfortunately it locks table B for updates and causes deadlock errors for  other transactions on B:

```
MySQL error code: 1213, SQLState: 40001, Msg: Deadlock found when trying to get lock;
try restarting transaction query: "UPDATE B set ... where id = ..."
```

We would like to have a lockless, non consistent isolation in the inner select. Is it possible? We perform the query periodically using EVENTs. Can we change the isolation level inside an event?

Our binlog format is `binlog_format = mixed`

Comment: You cannot have optimistic concurrency on the inner SELECT because its result-set is being used by the UPDATE so those `id`s need to be locked.

Comment: Use a `JOIN` instead of `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  How many rows do you typically change?

Comment: @RandolphWest I disagree that I can not or I should not. I agree that the resultset is non-determenistic.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by adding `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`. Each event invocation opens a fresh session so changing the session inside an event handler seems to be safe. Here is full code snippet:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS MY_EVENT ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2019-01-02 09:00:00'
    DO BEGIN
      /*  READ UNCOMMITTED should disable read locking during subquery selects */
      SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
      update A set status='INACTIVE' where status='ACTIVE' and b_id in
        (select id from B where ...);
    END;
```